# Can't iterate over complete HashSet

Tags: java

```
public class VenueManagement extends JApplet
{

    HashSet<Venue> vset;

    public void addValues()
    {
        vset = new HashSet<Venue>();
        Venue outstage = new VenueOut("Outdoor Stage");
        Venue libstage = new VenueOut("Library Stage");
        Venue audi = new VenueMB("Audi", true);
        Venue lt1 = new VenueMB("LT1", true);

        Event e1 = new Event("Drama", 11);
        Event e2 = new Event("Dance", 21);
        Event e3 = new Event("Music", 31);
        Event e4 = new Event("Art", 41);
        Event e5 = new Event("Literary", 51);
        Event e6 = new Event("Informals", 61);
        Event e7 = new Event("Sport", 71);
        Event e8 = new Event("Tech", 81);

        outstage.addEvent(1, e1);
        outstage.addEvent(2, e2);
        libstage.addEvent(3, e3);
        libstage.addEvent(4, e4);
        audi.addEvent(5, e5);
        audi.addEvent(6, e6);
        lt1.addEvent(7, e7);
        lt1.addEvent(8, e8);

        vset.add(outstage);
        vset.add(libstage);
        vset.add(audi);
        vset.add(lt1);

        Iterator<Venue> vset_iter = vset.iterator();
        while (vset_iter.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(vset_iter.next().vname + " AND " + vset_iter.next());
            System.out.println("***********************************************");
        }
    }

    // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////INIT////////////
    public void init()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        addValues();
        this.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

}
```

This is a part of a larger applet I'm trying to make. I was having problems so I identified it to this part of the program. 
I should theoretically be getting a list of all `vname` and corresponding `Venue` objects from lines 40 and 41, but I seem to be getting only this:

```
LT1 AND labexam.VenueMB@3559b0a6
***********************************************
Library Stage AND labexam.VenueOut@12fbbad2
***********************************************
```

I'm not getting the other two objects and their names for some reason.

It's a pretty straightforward code, I'm just creating an Iterator for `vset`, then iterating over it with a while loop.

Any clue?

Comment: I suspect the `hashCode()` or `equals()` methods in `Venue` being not quite right. What does `System.out.println( vset.size() )` print?

Answer (score 5):

`Iterator#next` returns the next element in the iteration

```
Iterator<Venue> vset_iter = vset.iterator();
while (vset_iter.hasNext()){
      Venue v= vset_iter.next();
      // you can retrieve the venue object's field here
      //System.out.println(v.vname + " AND " + v);
      //System.out.println("***********************************************");
}
```

Comment: Haha, well spotted. Yes, you shouldn't call `vset_iter.next()` twice, as it will advance the iterator twice (unsurprisingly).

Comment: Oookay that fixed it. I still don't get it though, how did we make any difference to the code? We just created a separate `Venue` object and then referred to it inside `println` instead of doing it directly.

EDIT: *facepalm* I get it I get it now.

Comment: yes, @user1265125 was calling `.next()` twice, which is a consuming operation.

Comment: @user1265125 share the `Vanue` class.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid calling next() twice within the loop, you are skipping Venues

```
Iterator<Venue> vset_iter = vset.iterator();
Venue venue;
    while (vset_iter.hasNext())
    {
        venue = vset_iter.next();
        System.out.println(venue.vname + " AND " + venue.otherString);
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
    }
```